# Character encoding : Web browsers, Latin-1 and € sign

Tags: html, browser, unicode, encoding, utf-8

I am trying to figure out what exactly IS unicode, utf-8, etc. I don't exactly understand **what a web browser does** and why, with content sent by the HTTP server.

Take this example :

In France, the website http://www.priceminister.com/ is said to be encoded in Latin-1

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
```

Question is :

**As € (euro sign) is not encoded in Latin-1, how is it possible that I actually see it on my screen?** (btw : too expensive)

Next question is :

If I scrape this web page, and decode it from Latin-1 to Unicode, what will happen to my €uro sign, which is not supposed to be encoded in Latin-1 in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The charset tells you how to interpret the "bytes", low level, before even figuring out the HTML syntax (parsing the HTML)

Latin 1 (ISO 8859-1) does not contain the Euro character.

But most browsers "know" that if you are declare your charset to be ISO 8859-1, but use bytes in the 80h-9Fh range, then you probably mean windows-1252 and use that instead
(https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252)

In fact all major browsers do charset detection and can detect more than windows-1252. You can of course dig and see what Firefox and Chrome do, as they are open source.

Another possibility is that the page uses a numeric or a named entity: &euro; or &#x20ac; or &#8364;. That is independent of the charset. So you can even have Euro, or Japanese, or Emojis in an ASCII file.

If you do scraping you can do what the browsers do and try to detect the charset. If you blindly trust the charset declaration the Euro will be lost.

If the pages uses entities then your html parser will probably interpret that for you (depends on the parser and how it is configured). If not, then you have to do the decoding yourself.

When scraping you must always do that unescaping (or have the parser do it) even if the charset declaration is correct. Nothing prevents me from using entities even in an utf-8 file.